# Example of delta method for iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.  I want to analyze the limiting distribution of $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ in a few cases:

(1) If $\mu \ne 0$, then we purely apply the delta method to the function $g(x) = 1/x$ to state that $$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{\bar{X}} - \frac{1}{\mu}\right) \rightarrow N(0, \sigma^2/\mu^4) $$ in distribution.

My question is what happens when $\mu = 0$?  Specifically what is is the limiting distribution of $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\bar{X}}$?  I'm a TA for undergraduate probability and was asked this by a student and gave them the following answer, though I said i wasn't sure.

I think there is no limiting distribution, but I'm guessing based on the following:  By the strong law of large numbers, $\bar{X} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.  Therefore, $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{|\bar{X}|} \rightarrow \infty \quad \text{almost surely} $$ so there is no limiting distribution (at least for real valued limits).

Is there a limiting distribution if we assume our limit can take values in the extended real line?  Define $Y_n :=  \sqrt{n}/\bar{X}$.  Since $-\bar{X}$ is equal in distribution to $\bar{X}$, we have $\lim_n Y_n \in \{-\infty, \infty\}$ if the limit exists (I wouldn't know how to show this), so that $P(\lim_n Y_n = \infty) = P(\lim_n Y_n = -\infty) = 1/2$ assuming that the limit exists almost surely.  I don't think this is correct though.  Am I right?

Comment: Just a remark: you defined $Y_n$ in a way that it is always positive and then talk as if you have removed the $|\cdot|$.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited to remove that error.  Thanks.

Comment: $$
\overline X \sim \operatorname N\left(0, \tfrac 1 n \right).
$$
If $x>0$ then
\begin{align}
f_{\sqrt n \,\overline X}(x) & = \frac d {dx} \Pr\left(\tfrac 1 {\sqrt n \, \overline X} \le x \right) = \frac d {dx} \Pr\left(\overline X \ge \frac 1 {x\sqrt n} \right) \\ {} \\
& = \frac d {dx} \int_{1/(x\sqrt n)}^{+\infty} \varphi(z) \, dz = \varphi\left( \tfrac 1 {x\sqrt n} \right) \cdot \tfrac 1 {x^2\sqrt n}
\end{align}
and similarly if $x<0.$ So maybe that's a staring point. $\qquad$

Comment: The limit of $\sqrt{n}/\overline{X}_n$ does not exist as it infinitely jumps between $\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Indeed $\sqrt{n}/|\overline{X}_n|\rightarrow \infty$ with prob 1 (with prob 1, $\overline{X}_n$ is never zero and eventually $\overline{X}_n$ is in the interval $(-1,1)$ and never leaves).